# How can I get a bigger Twitter Video size from the API?

Tags: twitter

When doing a search via the Twitter API, I get URLs to only small videos, for example:

```
u'video_info': {u'aspect_ratio': [1, 1],
                u'duration_millis': 98615,
                u'variants': [{u'bitrate': 320000,
                u'content_type': u'video/mp4',
u'url': u'https://video.twimg.com/ext_tw_video/944064088308510720/pu/vid/240x240/Dbol1j
YzSdt5A9Pi.mp4'},
               {u'content_type': u'application/x-mpegURL',
u'url': u'https://video.twimg.com/ext_tw_video/944064088308510720/pu/pl/6iSBw8vIHgtISD_
1.m3u8'}]}}]}
```

The video is only 240x240

How can I get a bigger version for resizing?

Comment: Are you able to provide any more information about the specific Tweet ID you're trying to retrieve? maybe it does not have any larger video size available?

Comment: I think you might be right. However, in this example https://video.twimg.com/tweet_video/DS0OBDTXkAECmEG.mp4 the video is smaller than the tweet https://twitter.com/Bit_docs/status/949430515093966851 and I can't seem to get it to the same size

Comment: Please provide Tweet IDs as media IDs are not individually queryable.

Comment: 949430515093966851

Comment: They look the same to me - that's an animated GIF so I'm guessing the size is dictated by the GIF dimensions before it was transcoded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I think you're looking for [the Media Size Objects](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/data-dictionary/overview/entities-object#media-size)**

> All Tweets with native media (photos, video, and GIFs) will include a set of ‘thumb’, ‘small’, ‘medium’, and ‘large’ sizes with height and width pixel sizes.

Also look at the overall [Media Objects](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/data-dictionary/overview/entities-object#media):

> The entities section will contain a media array containing a single media object if any media object has been ‘attached’ to the Tweet. If no native media has been attached, there will be no media array in the entities. **The has:media Operator will match if this array is populated.**

Ideally your code should check which media sizes exist and use whichever suits your site the best, since you can't rely on all of the sizes being there all the time.